# Delete Folder If Only Contains Text File

Tags: c#, directory.delete

I have been using this to delete empty folders, and it suits my needs perfectly.  I need to add one stipulation to still delete the folder if it only contains a  **SINGLE**  .txt file.  How should I alter this syntax to still delete the directory if it **only** contains a .txt file?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"C:\Test\";
}
public static void processDirectory(string startLocation)
{
    foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(startLocation))
    {
        processDirectory(directory);
        if (Directory.GetFiles(directory).Length == 0 && Directory.GetDirectories(directory).Length == 0)
        {
            Directory.Delete(directory, false);
        }
    }           
}
```

**EDIT**
This produces syntax error, but I think it is what I was trying to accomplish

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetExtension) == ".txt")
```

Comment: Inspect the result of `Directory.GetFiles(directory)` in your debugger, and try to see if you can figure out what to do besides checking its `Length`.

Comment: @takendarkk - I am not sure what starting point to take, I see you can use Path.GetExtension() to get a file extension, but how to do such in conjunction with Directory.GetFiles()

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` doesn't return one file, but a collection (which might include 1 file or many or none). You would have to iterate through the elements of this collection and check their names/extensions. Additionally `GetFiles` has overloads which can filter the type of files you want to get. You have basically tried to modify a working code without understanding what you were doing (and without performing any kind of research). SO is not the place to go when you do this kind of things.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public static void processDirectory(string startLocation)
{
    foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(startLocation))
    {
        processDirectory(directory);
        var aFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
        var noFiles = aFiles.Length == 0 || (aFiles.Length == 1 && aFiles.Count(file => Path.GetExtension(file) == ".txt") == 1);
        if (noFiles && Directory.GetDirectories(directory).Length == 0)
        {
            Directory.Delete(directory, true);
        }
    }           
}
```

UPDATE: OP modified question to specify a SINGLE file.  Answer modified to match.

Comment: Well, I'll modify the answer to remove the files.  But that's not what your original question was (which was to detect an empty directory or one with txt files in it).  If one of those files is locked, you're going to get an error too. So this is/was more of an example than something you should just copy and call "done".

Comment: @BoJackHorseman: From your comment I take it you tried to run this code. **Do not** run this on a folder that shouldn't be deleted, because it will delete *all* files in folders that contains *any* txt file.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey -- thank you, that was what I was after.  I sorry for my non clarity in the beginning!

Comment: @David - That's what he asked for.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey: No, OP put in bold that it should be deleted if it **only** contains a txt file. In your code, a folder with a txt file and a thousand photos will also be deleted.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey: Also, setting the [`recursive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter of `Directory.Delete` would've been enough to delete a non-empty file, your manual iteration is superfluous.

Comment: Ah. Right you are. Fixed.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey: Better. In this version, your check for `Length == 0` is redundant, as the `Count` on an empty folder will yield `0` txt files which will equal `aFiles.Length`. You have a syntax error in a superfluous `)` after `aFiles.Length`. But those are minor details. As for funcitonality, this will delete a folder with a thousand txt files, whereas I understand OP's "only contains a .txt file" to mean it should have to be a *single* txt file. I grant that this is a bit unclear, but given unclear directives, I'd rather delete too little than too much.

Comment: Yeah. I originally removed the length == 0 redundant and I think I fixed that trailing ) while you were commenting (or wait.. I screwed that up. I need coffee!). I put the length == 0 back in for clarity sake.  OP can remove it in his own usage if comfortable doing so.  I think the OP wasn't looking for single files per his response to my comment here. I agree the question could be worded better to include "only text files" or "a single text file".

Comment: @David At any rate, thanks for the assist. :) I up-voted your comments appropriately.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey - made edit to say only a single text file.  Again, sorry for my ignorance and lack of clarity

Comment: @BoJack - no worries. I modified the answer to match your question. Note that there are a number of ways to do this.  (you could use an Any() in this case, for example).  As it is now, it will trigger the delete if there is a single .txt file or no files at all.